# Gerar um XLS sem usar Excel (BIFF)

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Como gerar um arquivo `.xls` sem usar o Excel?
Não desejo usar o `OLE`, antes gostaria de inserir as informações em formato binário, usando a estrutura `BIFF8` ou alguma coisa parecida.
O problema é que não encontro documentação, nem mesmo no **MSDN**!

Alguém conhece como é estruturado o `BIFF8`?
Ou tem alguma ideia de como exportar um relatório para Excel sem usar o Excel?

Detalhes:

- Delphi XE7
- pReport (Gerador de relatórios)

Comment: o componente cxGrid da DevExpress, tem uma técnica de exportação interessante, porem complexa. Se você estiver disposto a usar esse componente, eu poderia te dar uma ajuda.

Comment: @VictorZanella sempre ajudando kkk. Obrigado mas preciso resolver nativamente mesmo, sem componentes de terceiro.. ainda mais pagos.

Comment: Cara, parece ser uma tarefa complicada. Tem alguns frameworks gratuitos que fazem isso, não quer dar uma olhada? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493071/exporting-to-excel-from-delphi-without-having-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta poderá ser uma solução para o seu problema, basta criar uma tabela em `html` e exportar como `Xls`, exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var XlsFile: TextFile;
    i: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(XlsFile, 'C:\report.xls');
  Rewrite(XlsFile);
  writeln(XlsFile, '<HTML><BODY><table>');
  writeln(XlsFile, '<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
  writeln(XlsFile, '<tr><td>Test</td><td>Test2</td></tr>');
  writeln(XlsFile, '<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
  writeln(XlsFile, '</table></body></html>');
  CloseFile(XlsFile);
end;
```

Alguma dúvida ou questão coloque, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: sua sugestão é válida, porém a exportação do relatório para HTML fica bem complicada. Isso porque terei de gerar inúmeros `<tr><td>` porque os dados não estão estruturados como uma tabela, mas é um relatório gráfico. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: como se encontrão os seus dados?

Comment: Podemos comparar o relatório a um PDF, e cada informação visível nesse relatório eu posso trabalhar como se fosse um `Label`, onde tenho apenas o conteúdo e a posição (`TRect`).  Assim faço um **loop** e de acordo com a posição, vou jogando em células específicas do Excel (atualmente usando`OLE`).

Comment: ok, se me lembrar de algo mais que possa ajudar eu comunico

Comment: @Andrey da uma olhada na documentação sobre o padrão BIFF do excel aqui neste link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.14).aspx